# Why Spring does not show compilation error with AbstractHttpMessageConverter if JACKSON is not present in classpath

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

Spring document says that the Jackson 2 API should be present in the classpath for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to work.

In the source code of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, Spring is importing the classes from jackson API.

31 --> import  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding; 
32 --> import  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator; 
33 --> import  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType; 
34 --> import  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Now my question is if JACKSON is not present in the classpath then the above code in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter should throw an compile time error. But why does not this class has any compilation error.

Comment: How do yo know that MappingJackson2HttpMessageCoverter project has Jackson API not in the classpath? Can you referr to project code please?

Answer (score 3):

First, Spring is using reflection to determine if the Jackson library is on the classpath. You can see that in action in [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java):

```
private static final boolean jackson2Present =
        ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", 
            WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class.getClassLoader()) &&
        ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator",       
            WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class.getClassLoader());
```

Now `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` itself also has the following: `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`.

But two things come into play here:

- those classes are needed at compile time **for Spring Framework**, not your application; just like all libraries supported by Spring, they're optional dependencies in Spring's build
- those classes, even if declared as imports in a class, are only loaded by the JVM when they're used/read.

The same constraints apply to Spring 4.x for its JDK8 support, while still working on JDK6+. See [this blog post for more details](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8).